# How to Compare water heater recovery specs with different TRise numbers

Tags: plumbing, water-heater

I'm in the process of replacing my water heater.  The only specs I know from my existing water heater are those listed on the label shown below. [image].

At first I wanted to compare FHR specs, but I can't find those for my existing water heater.  If someone can find it, I'd be appreciative.  Instead, I thought I'd look at the Recovery Rating (upper right corner of pictured label).

My plumber is offering the BradfordWhite RG240T6N.  It seems to be quite comparable.  I'd like to compare the recovery rating, but the [spec sheet](https://s3.amazonaws.com/bradfordwhitecorp/wp-content/uploads/residential_gas_natural_atmospheric_vent_naeca_compliant_specsheet_1101.pdf) lists the recovery rating at a 90F rise, while the label on my heater shows a 100F rise.

Existing heater:  33.9 gallons at 100F rise
BM water heater:  43 gallons at 90F rise

So how do I compare these two?  I'm getting 10 more gallons from the BM heater, but at 10 degrees less.  So...will we run out of hot water slower or faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do the calculation I looked at BTUs retained by the water. If we assume water weighs 8.34 pounds per gallon and 1 BTU raises 1 pound of water by 1 degree we can go from that.

Tank1: 33.9 Gal 100F
33.9 x 8.34 = 282.726  -  282.726 x 100 = 28,272 BTU

Tank2: 43 Gal 90F
43 x 8.34 = 358.62  -  358.62 x 90 = 32,275 BTU

My choice would be Tank #2, It is also probably more efficient.